# File transfer from Google Compute engine to Google Storage

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have read the documentation for Google Cloud Storage(GCS) and I am very confused.

Let me describe the situation:

**Before**
I am using a simple php script to back up data from and SQL Table. At every one hour. Afterwards I sent it to my ftp server.
**Now**
Now I would like instead to be sent to a google nearline cold storage.

Before the script was simple, nothing fancy just a little PHP

```
passthru('curl --connect-timeout 30 --max-time 3600 -T '.$file_path.' "ftp://'.$ftp_server['user'].':'.$ftp_server['pass'].'@'.$ftp_server['ip'].':'.$ftp_server['port'].$ftp_server['path'].'/'.$filename.'.gz"', $status_result);
```

Now I read the google cloud API and I am very confused of actually how to change my PHP script, so that it sends the gz files to the nearline cold storage.

I read this: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/

and I have the following questions

- It says that I have to include the google API, how do I do that? In the example it said that I should use the command "*$ composer require google/cloud*" and then write in my PHP files: "*use Google\Cloud\ServiceBuilder;*" But I haven't use composer on the server. The server is written on pure PHP.

  1. If I have a simple php file (history_dump.php for example), how do I include the google cloud API as external link?
  2. The way I have done it now is SQL -> csv -> gz, I don't want to change that can I send gz files to GCS? How?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have also written a php script now but it gives me an error like this: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized X-GUploader-UploadID: ********_7hxso Vary: Origin Vary: X-Origin WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error=invalid_token Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 249 Date: Fri, 21 Jul 2017 14:50:50 GMT Server: UploadServer { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }

Comment: The `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` response indicates you are not passing the right credentials for authentication. You can read about [`Authentication`](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/) and [`Application Default Credentials`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) to understand how you can configure and pass the credentials for your API call to Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just keep using a little script? GCE comes with `gsutil` installed, which you can use to transfer files to GCS. Try this:

```
passthru('gsutil cp '.$filepath.' gs://bucket/', $status_result);
```

Note that, for auth to work, you'll have to make sure your instance's service account is scoped to access GCS, see: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes

Comment: Hi I think your comment is very relevant, as you can see I am a newbie php dev. So I read for the functions where you can use to call unix comands, such as system(), exec() and ofc passthru().

But I am missing something, because even though I write it, as you said I should. I think my auth is not right, after I execute the script it returns '1', which is an error. 

Currently my "Cloud API access scopes" for "Storage" is set to "Read only" do you think the problem lies in this?

Comment: A little more information for debuging, if I run this:

passthru( "gcloud -h" , $status_result2); 

and I echo the result variable it actually works?

Comment: Thank you for the answer it helped! As for my other question it was related to the service account scope
>For example, if you had created your VM with devstorage.read_only scope, trying to write to a bucket would fail, even if your service account has permission to write to the bucket. You would need devstorage.full_control or devstorage.read_write.